# Android поддержка векторных форматов

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня в проекте минимальная версия API 18.

Я хочу использовать векторные картинки из библиотеки стандартных значков. На старших версиях все нормально.
А вот на минимальной падает при получении drawable и занесении в список, чтобы передать в recyclerView adapter

```
val listAttachFiles = ArrayList<AttachFile>();
        listAttachFiles.add(AttachFile(0, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_image_24), "Галерея"))
        listAttachFiles.add(AttachFile(1, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_camera_blue_24), "Камера"))
        listAttachFiles.add(AttachFile(2, resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_file_green_24), "Файл"))
        attachFilesAdapter.updateData(listAttachFiles)
```

Ошибка

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_image_24.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700c1. If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:695)
        at com.app.peshkariki.Fragment.attachFiles.AttachFilesBottomSheetDialogFragment.onViewCreated(AttachFilesBottomSheetDialogFragment.kt:37)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:322)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:897)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:837)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
```

Почитав некоторые связанные проблема, я выяснил, что поддержка векторых форматов у меня уже включена была

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Какие еще варианты есть для возможности работы с данным типом файлов?

data class

```
data class AttachFile(
    val id: Int,
    var image: Drawable,
    var title: String
)
```

Как использовал

```
itemView.image.setImageDrawable(attachFiles.image)
```

**Update**

Теперь в Adapter захардкордил

```
when(attachFiles.id){
                0 -> itemView.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_24)
                1 -> itemView.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera_blue_24)
                2 -> itemView.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_file_green_24)
            }
```

Но на API < 21 картинка не показывается

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()`

Так же убедитесь, что ic_image.xml лежит именно в drawable, а не в drawable-v21 и подобных.